# Create a user in IronMQ via API

Tags: java, iron.io, ironmq

I'm trying to set up a message queue service for an application I am developing.

I already tried AWS SQS, but it doesn't really fit for our needs, mainly for the issues with the FIFO and the limited message persistence.

So I turned to IronMQ, to see how this could work, but I'm already having issues with the creation of users via java APIs.

There's no class dedicated and it seems nobody cares about that. Does anybody know anything about how to do that? Do I have to write my own APIs?

EDIT: as manveru pointed out, I'm talking about tokens, not users.
Another issue is about setting other permissions than "Admin", but I guess I'll confront it later.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with `creation of users`? Do you mean new tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, our API doesn't support creating new access tokens. I think it's something that could be really powerful, though (generate a token per server as part of the build process, for example).

I've [created an issue](https://github.com/iron-io/issues/issues/24) in our global issue tracker. If you like, you can follow that to get a notification when something on this front changes. We have a lot of stuff we're working on right now, so I can't even guess at a timeline, unfortunately. :(

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the steady answer, I'm surely going to follow the issue you created, since the creation and removal of tokens via API is mandatory for the application I'm working on.

Comment: If you'd like to chat with our team about your requirements, everyone (including our executive team) mans the chatroom at get.iron.io/chat. Feel free to stop by!